# Override Magento Class (Adminhtml-View)

Tags: magento, module, overriding, extend

I want to extend the given class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View for adding some more buttons. But that's not the problem: My custom class won't load.

What am I missing?

**app/etc/modules/Cb_Adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cb_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Cb_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Cb/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cb_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Cb_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
         <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_invoice_view>Cb_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View</sales_order_invoice_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
     </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Cb/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Invoice/View.php**

```
<?php

class Cb_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(get_class($this)); exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The module name you've chosen might cause a conflict. Change it from `Adminhtml` to something else and try again.